# Node events.js:292 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs

I'm trying to bundle my ios build using this command:

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

but everytime I try to get this error:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:127:28)
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:143:12)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:133:12) {
  errno: -24,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  filename: null
}
```

I've tried the following: killnode command, install watchman, restart machine, delete node_modules folder and npm install. So far none have worked and the error keeps showing.

Comment: I know the OP said that deleting `node_modules` didn't work, but I deleted that, and `yarn.lock`, and the build then worked as normal, so worth a shot for anyone looking at this

Answer (score 0):

It may just be that you need to raise the open file limit.

Try using `ulimit 4096` and see how that works?

That way, instead of addressing the root cause, you may be able to work around it.

It may just be that your system is configured too low for the actual standard react build process, and that nothing is wrong.

You can also, although it's not strongly advised to set an unlimited limit too.

`ulimit unlimited`. If doing this it's recommended to set a soft limit via the `-S` flag: `ulimit -S unlimited` as to not exceed your ram.

Comment: typed ulimit 4096 into the terminal and then ran the bundle command but still didn't work :(

Comment: Don't just set ``ulimit 4096``... I'm not sure what that does, but it does **not** raise the allowed number of open *file descriptors*. Use ``ulimit -n [some integer]``.  https://linuxhint.com/linux_ulimit_command/

Comment: How are you using the command? ``ulimit [some integer]`` or ``ulimit -n [some integer]``? Because those do different things.

Comment: My bad. @Take-Some-Bytes is right. However, with -n, it won't work if the amount is higher than your hard limit you've set. It also only applies to your current terminal session when run in the terminal. Make sure to run it in the session you're running the command in.

Comment: You can check your full breakdown on your user's limits with `ulimit -a`